# Secure REST API calls from a C# based application to a PHP, holding personal information such as login credentials, private messages?

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I am currently working on a Xamarin Studio Forms application where I both get and post data with REST-api calls. I do this with both messaging and also by storing login credentials. With my current frontend C# and backend PHP setup I can successfully login users, but now i wish to add security to the whole thing.

Right now to see if a your user credentials are correct I do this:

```
static public async Task<JObject> LoginUser(string Email, string Password)
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync(”http://myURL.com/Signingup/Login.php?Email=" + Email + "&Password=" + Password);
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
        return jsonResult;
    }

    catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I retrieve it with this PHP code:

```
<?php

class ConnectionInfo 
{ 
    public $conn; 
    public function GetConnection() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect(”server”, ”user”,”pass”, ”db”) or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));
    }
}

$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
    echo 'No Connection';
}
else
{
    $Email = $_GET['Email'];
    $Password = $_GET['Password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Email = '$Email' AND Password = '$Password'";

    $stmt = mysqli_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
    echo 'Query failed';
    }

    else
    {
        $contacts = array();
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) 
        {
            $contact = array("Email" => utf8_encode ($result['Email']),"Password" => utf8_encode  ($result['Password']),
            "UserID" => ($result['UserID']));
            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        echo json_encode ($contact, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

}

?>
```

This works and I can successfully retrieve the data in my C# application and successfully login a user. But now the security aspects comes in. How would I secure this?

I read briefly about ”hashing” but also about creating ”sessiontokens” but I am unsure on which way to go/which way would be the best and most secure approach.

When I looked at an old example with ”Parse” I saw that they added a App-ID key and a REST Api key with all their httpClientRequest calls, looking like this:

```
httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-Application-Id", appIdString);
httpClientRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", apiKeyString);
```

Could this be a good way to approach it? If it is and I add these headers to my `GetAsync` call, what would I then need to do with my PHP code in order to retrieve the call?

This is the signup code:
C#

```
 static public async Task<JObject> SignupUser(string Email, string Password)
 {
   var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();
   var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   try
   {
     postData.Add("Email", Email);
     postData.Add("Password", Password);

     var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
     HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("http://url.com/Signup/Signup.php", content);
     var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
     return jsonResult;
   }
   catch {
     return null;
  }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$mysql_pekare= new mysqli ("serv", "user","pass", "db");

if(!empty($value)) {

        $stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO Login (`Email`, `Password`)  VALUES(?,?)"); 
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value->Email, $value->Password);
        printf(mysqli_insert_id());
        $stmt->execute();

        if(!empty($stmt)) {
            session_start();
            $contacts = array(); 
            $id = mysqli_insert_id(); 
            $contact = array("UserID" =>  ($stmt->insert_id));
            array_push($contacts, $contact);
            echo json_encode ($contact, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

            $stmt->close();
            $mysql_pekare->close();     
        }
    }


  }

  ?>
```

Comment: There is a _lot_ wrong with this login system. It's using GET instead of POST, it's using user input directly in queries (read about SQL injection), it's storing passwords in plaintext. And then you return the just-provided email and password if they were correct. Then the authorization aspect comes into play: how do you check that a caller can perform a certain action? I'd rebuild this from the ground on up, using a well tested authentication and authorization framework for PHP. Don't create security systems by yourself.

Comment: `I read briefly about ...`: try to read some more. There are some issues with your code. 1) don't send sensitive information as a querystring since it's not secure. 2) read about SQL injection 3) don't store login credentials, as they can be stolen.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, it will save me lots of time. And yes, this is the first "login system" i've created so i expected that there would be many flaws.

Comment: If youre familiar with c# and .net you can take a look at the implementation of identityserver. Or the implementation of oauth2 and openid in general.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using post during the register-process. This is the login process where i GET the data that is in the DB and compare it to the inputted fields. I have edited the post with that code too.